# Find $x\in \Bbb R,$ solving $x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, real-numbers, nested-radicals

> Given: $x\in \mathbb R$, $x=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}$
>
> Find: numeric value of $x$

Problem from a math contest. Sorry if it is a duplicate, but could not find anything similar using the search tool.

**My attempt:** I squared both sides, and developed the resulting expression, but I'm getting to nowhere.

Hints and/or answers please.

Is there any standard way to approach problems like these?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I don't actually think that in a contest situation more squaring would get you anywhere. I personally couldn't solve the resulting equation by hand.

Comment: If $s(x):=\sqrt{1+x}$ then we are looking for a fixed point of
 $f:=s\circ s\circ s$ but a fixed point of $s$ is also a fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Squaring is not the way to go. I got to an eight degree equation. Not easily solvable. @orlp solution is great.

Comment: This the golden Ration see below

Comment: Guys, it is trivial that any solution of $x=f(x)$ is a solution of $x=f(f(f(x)))$, but here we have to prove the *converse* statement to be sure $x=\varphi$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We know that the Golden ratio $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ and $~\bar{\phi}= \frac{1 -\sqrt5}{2}$ satisfy  the equation 
$$x^2 = 1+x  \Longleftrightarrow x= \sqrt {1 + x}~~x>0~ \implies x= f(x)$$ where, $f(x)=  \sqrt {1 + x},~~x>0.$
This means that $ \phi $ is  the only fix points of the function $f(x)=  \sqrt {1 + x},~x>0$

But $$ \sqrt {1 + \sqrt {1 + \sqrt{1+x}}} = f\circ f\circ f(x)= f^3(x) .$$

> Therefore your equation reduces to 
>   $$x= f^3(x)$$

Which mean that $x$ is fix point of $f^3$.

On the other hand, $|f'(x)| =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+1}} \le \frac12$ then,

$$|(f^3(x))'| =  3|f'(x)\cdot f'(f^2)(x)| \le \frac 34<1$$

**then $f^3$ is a contraction and hence,  $f^3$ has  a unique fix point satisfying** $x=f^3(x)$ . Whereas, 
 $$ \color{red}{x= f^3(x) \implies  f(x) = f^3(f(x)) \implies x= f(x) }$$

since we observse that **$f(x)$ is also a point fix of $f^3$
 by unicity? we get $x=f(x).$**

But $\phi $ is the only positive number satisfying $x=f(x)$.

> Hence, the only solution to $x=f^3(x)$ is $$x=\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}~$$

Comment: your fully right I messed up with implications check the edit now you will be satisfy. that was first my original idea0 thank for notifying me

Comment: you did not down voted me ?

Comment: No, I prefer to point out mistakes and to upvote fixed answers, rather than blindly downvoting answers that are simple to fix.

Comment: ok  thabks I wish the owner of the down vote to give his opinion now

Answer (score 8):

Clearly any solution of the given equation is a positive real number.

**Lemma**. The map $x\mapsto \sqrt{1+x}$ is a contraction over $[0,+\infty)$, since for every $x\geq 0$ we have $\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{x+1}\leq\frac{1}{2}<1$.

**Corollary**. By the [Banach fixed point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem), $x=\sqrt{1+x}$ has a unique real solution. Simple algebra gives that such a solution is provided by the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

**Lemma**. Since $f(x)$ is a contraction over $[0,+\infty)$, $f(f(f(x)))$ is a contraction *a fortiori*.

**Corollary**. By the Banach fixed point Theorem, the given equation has a unique real solution. $x=\varphi$ is a solution, hence it is the only one.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the solution is unique(which you can find out yourself). Then there is another function has the same solution to this one:

$x=\sqrt{1+x} $

Done

Comment: How do you know the solution of $x=\sqrt{1+x}$ is the solution of OP's equation?

Comment: because you can plug in this solution to OP's equation and it still works

Comment: That works with infinitely nested radicals, not here.

Comment: it literally works, just replace the right hand side by the left hand side, you will see

Comment: Let $y(x) = \sqrt{1+x}$. Then OP is asking about $x=y(y(y(x)))$. If we know a solution to $x=y(x)$ then we will have $x=y(y(y(x))) = y(y(x))=y(x)=x$, no?

Comment: your calculation is wrong

Comment: X=(1+5^0.5)/2 =1.618, (1+(1+(1+X)^0.5)^0.5)^0.5=1.618=X

Comment: @5xum While I disagree that lion's answer is clear, you are wrong about that. See for example: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(1+%2B+sqrt(1+%2B+sqrt(1+%2B+(1+%2B+sqrt(5))%2F2+)))+%3D%3D+(1+%2B+sqrt(5))%2F2

Comment: @TonyS.F. right

Comment: 5xum, you can easily see that (if the solution is unique) it has to hold $$x=\sqrt{1+x}$$. Assume x is a solution then it holds $$\begin{align*} & x =\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}} \\ \iff & \sqrt{1+x} = \sqrt{1+ \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}}} \\ &\iff y = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+y}}}\end{align*}$$ for $$y = \sqrt{1+x}$$ so the equation also holds for $y$. Because the solution is unique it follows $$x = y = \sqrt{1+x}$$

Comment: @Gono this is what the answer is missing.

Comment: OK yeah I was mistyping something, in fact $x=\sqrt{1+x}$ is the correct equation. However, I still think this answer is very unclear.

Comment: Answers don't necessarily need to explain every step in detail. In fact, OP asked for hints as well as answers. Surely you agree that what lion has written is at least a hint, right @5xum ?

Comment: @Gono: you are right that one only needs to show $x=f(f(f(x)))\Longrightarrow x=f(x)$, but that is not trivial.

Comment: @lion: please see my comment under the main question and my previous comment here. Your solution is not complete: every solution of $x=f(x)$ is a solution of $x=f(f(f(x)))$, of course, but *why* there aren't other solutions of $x=f(f(f(x)))$, different from the ones of $x=f(x)$? That is the main concern.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, because as I stated in the first place, the solution is unique to begin with

Comment: @lion: and I am just asking: *why*? That is not trivial.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio because the left minus the right is monotonous by looking at the first derivative, "which you can find out yourself"

Comment: Well, but most of the problem stays there, surely not in the observation that $x=f(x)$ implies $x=f(f(f(x)))$. There are a lot of details to be filled before being allowed to state *done*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + x}$. The only thing we need is $f(x)$ is a strictly increasing function in $x$.

When $f(x) \ne x$, we have two posibilities:

- $f(x) > x \implies f(f(x)) > f(x) \implies f(f(f(x))) > f(f(x))$.
  Combine these, we have
  $$f(x) > x \implies f(f(f(x))) > f(f(x)) > f(x) > x \implies f(f(f(x)) > x$$
- $f(x) < x \implies f(f(x)) < f(x) \implies f(f(f(x))) < f(f(x))$.
  Combine these, we have
  $$f(x) < x \implies f(f(f(x))) < f(f(x)) < f(x) < x \implies f(f(f(x))) < x$$

In both cases, we have $f(f(f(x))) \ne x$. What this means is in order to solve
$$x = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x}}} = f(f(f(x)))$$
we need to have 
$$x = f(x) = \sqrt{1+x} \quad\iff\quad x^2 = 1 + x\quad\implies\quad x = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
Please note that the other root of the quadratic polynomial has been ruled out because it is negative.