# Is what I have got about $\int\sqrt{x+\left(\sqrt{{x}+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}\right)}dx$ true or false?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, nested-radicals

I want to calculate the antiderivative of this function .

$$ y(x) = \sqrt{x+\left(\sqrt{{x}+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}\right)}$$

**Attempt:**

let $y = \sqrt{x + y}$ then:  $\displaystyle\int {ydy=\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+y}}}+c =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\left(\sqrt{{x}+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}\right)}}}+c$  or it must to integrate with respect to $x$ ?

Comment: Hint: Try to find a simpler expression for $y$ before you integrate. You need to be a bit careful with the convergence.

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480022/find-x-in-bbb-r-solving-x-sqrt1-sqrt1-sqrt1x/2480069#2480069

Comment: @Jack Wonder What do you want to integrate it with ? y or x?

Comment: I want to integrate for x as shown in the title

Comment: If the differential element in the integral is $dx$ then integrate with respect to $x$, by converting all $y$ into $x$. Look, whatever is the variable of integration, in this case which is $x$, there shouldn't be another variable present which depends on previous, which is $y$. If you want to integrate w.r.t $y$, surely you can but you need to change the varibles accordingly. You will have to find relation between $dx$ and $dy$ and the properly replace $dx$ with $dy$, remove $x$ completely from the expression, and then you are all set to integrate w.r.t. $y$.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to some fruitful  discussion with **@MPW4** your initial expression makes any sense before hand in $\Bbb R$ only if $x>0$

From now we assume $x>0.$ otherwise $y(x)$ might clearly be undefined as well.  we have $$y = \sqrt{x+\left(\sqrt{{x}+\sqrt{x+\cdots}}\right)}\implies y(x) = \sqrt{x+y(x)}~~~~y(x)\ge 0\\ \implies y^2(x)-y(x)-x=0, ~~~~y(x)\ge 0
\\\implies  y(x)\equiv y_\pm(x) = \frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}~~~~y(x)\ge 0$$

Hence you have to choose one branch, either $y_-$ or $y_+$ 
 but using the constraints, $x\ge 0~~$ and $~~y(x)\ge 0$ show that the only possible value is given by, 
$$ y(x)= y_+ = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$$

since $$y_-(x)\ge 0\implies x\le 0$$

> Conclusion we have $ y(x)= y_+ = \frac{1+\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}$ and 
>   $$\int y(x)dx = \frac{x+\frac{1}{6}(1+4x)^{3/2}}{2}$$

Addendum:

> But rather you could consider $x\equiv x(y) $ as function of $y$ variable then, you obviously get 
>   $$ \int x(y)dy = \int y^2-ydy=\frac{1}{3}y^3-\frac{1}{2}y^2$$

Comment: Your conclusion is incorrect. There may be two values of $y$ which satisfy your derived quadratic, but that doesn't mean they are both the limiting value (for a given $x$, $y$ is defined as a limit, after all). You have simply introduced an extraneous root by squaring both sides. The only reasons $y(x)$ could be undefined are (1) some term in the sequence is undefined (e.g., square root of a negative number) and (2) the sequence diverges. Your reasoning applied to the function $y=x$ would produce $y^2(x) = x^2$ and then $y(x)=\pm\sqrt{x^2} = \pm|x|$.

Comment: @MPW  Yes agree with you but the OP has given no precision nor restriction on y and x. so I did not want to decide for him

Comment: but He assumed that is undefined as well and He concluded that y(x) is not necessarily a function

Comment: @GuyFsone , but where is the antiderivative of this function since OP requered it ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik the OP you should decide to choose one branch functions I proposed otherwise it is not a function. I think in such cases it is baby analysis

Comment: Do you meant since it has two formula ?

Comment: You can't just "pick a branch". For positive $x$, only the "$+$" branch could possibly be the actual value of $y$. If you choose the "$-$" branch, then the resulting $y$ is negative (the radicand is greater than $1$, so the difference is negative). This is clearly impossible since you are just taking a sequence of square roots of positive numbers. As I mentioned, YOU have introduced the ambiguous sign by squaring. There AREN'T two branches.

Comment: @MPW note that both branch are perfectly defined for $x\ge -\frac14$. and $y_-(x)\ge 0$ and defined only for $-\frac14\le x\le 0$. so both branch can still be considered.

Comment: When $x<0$, the function is undefined, assuming we're working in the real domain. For example, the value of $y$ when $x=-\tfrac19$ would have to be the limit of the sequence $$\sqrt{-\tfrac19},\sqrt{-\tfrac19+\sqrt{-\tfrac19}},\sqrt{-\tfrac19+\sqrt{-\tfrac19+\sqrt{-\tfrac19}}},\ldots$$ but non of these terms are defined.

Comment: @MPW yeaaar that could be a good an actually it is a surprising result. you start with complex and end with real number

Comment: and there is no problem with negative number just to move to the integration over C

Comment: @MPW I have edited the post once more it should fine . and you have been cited

Comment: @GuyFsone For your addendum, I believe that you forgot to multiply by $dy$. This is a u-substitution for $y= \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+...}}}$, $y^2 - y = x$, $$dy(2y-1) =dx$$. I believe the integral should be $$\int (2y-1)(y) dy$$